# compare two string variables ignoring case

Tags: vba, excel

I need to compare 2 variable in an If statement but i still want it to refurn true if everything is the same except the cases. I know  can't write this but here is a sense of what I am looking to do:

```
If (str1=str2 matchcase:=false) then
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the fastest, you'll want to use StrComp()

StrComp will do several tests to avoid having to actually compare the string or whole string that makes it faster when strings differ.  If you do expect a lot of common values, you may avoid StrComp but for the most part it is faster.

```
100M comparisons with same phrase but different case:
LCase = 20 seconds
StrComp = 23 seconds *This is a rare case

100M comparisons with different phrase but same length
LCase = 20 seconds
StrComp = 9 seconds

100M comparisons with different phrase and different length
LCase = 25 seconds
StrComp = 9 seconds
```

NOTE: Lengths of strings will vary the results. For example, on the last test, LCase took longer than the other tests because I doubled the length of one of the strings.  This slowed LCase down but not StrComp.

NOTE2: LCase and UCase had similar results.

Answer (score 7):

`If (lcase(str1)=lcase(str2)) then`

Answer (score 5):

Though i prefer @mr.Reband answer but still you may refer this alternative which uses `StrComp` function.

```
Sub test()

Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String

str1 = "test"
str2 = "Test"

MsgBox StrComp(str1, str2, vbTextCompare)


'Return Values
'
'The StrComp function has the following return values:
'
'If StrComp returns
'string1 is less than string2 -1
'string1 is equal to string2 0
'string1 is greater than string2 1
'string1 or string2 is Null Null

End Sub
```